# Revert plotly html graph back to plolty object to use in dash

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I'm making a dashboard for a BI/DS project.

So far I've managed to make all ETL pipelines and even built some endpoints in flask_RESTful to present single graphs generated using plotly.

However, since I use Flask_RESTful, my code returns *all graphs in div format*.

Now I want to use them in **dash** without having to duplicate or change my code (I want to keep the raw html backends so the client can embed it in his own website if wanted).

This is what I return in my back-end:

```
return plotly.offline.plot(fig, filename='plot', include_plotlyjs=False, auto_open=False,
                                   config={"displayModeBar": False, "showTips": False}, output_type='div')
```

How do I insert that into my dash layout?

If I do

```
dash_app.layout = html.Div(children=[
                    html.H1(children=my_plot_function())
                  ])
```

All I get is raw html (string)

**Is there some way to revert the "plot as div" function in plotly to use them in dash?**

(Using Dash is much simpler for me than trying to learn React or anything like that)